# can reversing a very inaccurate binary classifier give more accurate predictions?

Tags: classification, accuracy, precision-recall

I was wondering if somehow I get a model for binary classification with let us say a 0.30 accuracy, does this means that if I reverse the outcome of the model (ie. swapping 0s and 1s in the predictions) could result in a higher accuracy (0.70)?

I know it seems very illogical (and maybe dumb question), but I cannot find any good explanation of why or why not this is not possible, **and also** how that applies for other metrics such as recall, precision...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this would not work. As the accuracy is the sum of correct predictions (0 and 1), divided by the total predictions. Consider the following cross-table for reference:

```
true    1    0
model
1       a    b
0       c    d
```

The formula for accuracy would be `acc = (a+d)/(a+b+c+d)`. As the values for `a` and `d` just switch if you exchange 1 and 0, the result would be exactly the same.

However, it would make a difference for precision, recall, and F. Here, the denomination of the positive value (0 or 1) is important as these scores focus on the true positives in contrast to false negatives or false positives.

- Precision is the share of true positives in all positive predicted: `precision=a/(a+b)`. If you switch 1 and 0, this would become `precision = d/(c+d)`.
- Recall is the share of true positives in all actually positive cases: `recall = a/(a+c)`. Here, flipping would change the formula to `recall = d/(d+b)`.

So, the impact of flipping 1 and 0 depends on the coefficients you are interested in. It *should, however not rely* on the impact on coefficients but on the actual theoretical meaning of present (1) and absent (0) in your specific case.

Comment: Can you specify please when exactly and how the precision and recall could go higher after switching 0 and 1 ?

Comment: This would happen if the count in the d-cell is much higher than the count in the a-cell. You get this, sometimes, when your test data is biased and you have more negative cases (0) in it.